# Why was the Congressional Apportionment Amendment opposed?

Tags: united-states, constitution, us-congress

The [Congressional Apportionment Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_Apportionment_Amendment) only established a principal for congressional apportionment, which was followed out of custom for many years after the adoption of the constitution. If these principles were to be followed anyway, why was the amendment opposed? Did it differ between opposing states?

Comment: @Schwern I see you edited this. Do you have an answer?

Comment: If I did, I'd have written it. :) I just added the Wikipedia link so myself (and others) know what you're talking about. I didn't. It seems to me the Wikipedia article explains what happened. Are you looking for something more?

Comment: @Schwern It never really explains why people opposed it.